# Не могу использовать UI компонент, выдаётся warn

Tags: vue.js, vuex

```
<my-button v-for="item in $store.state.button" class="catalog__filter-button" :item="item"></my-button>
```

Первое что я делаю на странице, это отправляю запрос на сервер (mysql, phpmyadmin) и после, полученную дату я записываю в store.
Но когда я прохожусь по $store.state.button, выдаётся варн:

```
[Vue warn]: Extraneous non-props attributes (item, categoryNow, class) were passed to component but could not be automatically inherited because component renders fragment or text root nodes. 
  at <MyFilterButton item= {id: 6, category: 3} categoryNow="she" class="catalog__filter-button" > 
  at <CatalogView onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< Proxy(Object) {loadData: ƒ, loadCategory: ƒ, loadFilter: ƒ, …} > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
```

Ко всему к тому же, страница почему-то загружается два раза
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня мало опыта работы с клиентом на вью и бэком, поэтому ошибка может быть банальной

Comment: $store.state.button  --->   somevalue = computed -> получить из store.state.button
https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/ru/guide/list.html#%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-v-for

Answer (score 0):

Исправил ошибку, надо было в ui компоненте в export default написать `inheritAttrs: false,`.